# Miscellaneous quests disappearing from quest log?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just as the title says, I've had quite a few miscellaneous quests disappear from my quest log, and it's starting to bother me now as I fear they'll never come back. I can't say for sure how many (or *which*) have disappeared, but I know for sure that the quest where I have to take the unusual gem to an appraiser was one of the ones that seems to have disappeared very recently. There may be more, but this one stands out in particular.

Is there any reason why this has happened? Clashing quests perhaps or have I lost it/them forever? :(

Comment: This is a stupid question, but is it possible that you completed them without realizing it? Like with the Unusual Gem, do you now have a quest to gather 24 Stones of Barenziah?

Comment: This happens to me even as of today with all unofficial patches. Quests sometimes disappear from Misc, but if you complete an objective that has disappeared, it is marked completed with the quest notification. Usually this happens whenever I do a save file clean-up, deleting old saves and keeping only recent ones. But not always.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit Riften for the first time, right there at the entrance, a guy on the left side will stop you and talk to you. You then show him your gem, ask what its worth, and by this conversation, the quest (take the gem to an appraiser) will be removed and a follow-up quest starts, in which you must join the Thieves Guild, so you get access to Vex, which is the "appraiser" you were looking for.

If you have visited Riften, and have been talked to by that guy at the city's entrance, then your quest did not just vanish, but "upgrade" itself to the next level. Check if you have the MISC quest "Join the Thieves Guild". If you have it, all is good. Join the guild and talk to Vex. If you do not have the Thieves Guild quest, my knowledge is at an end.

Hope that helped,
FRU33